# How to handle "Cannot match any routes" error?

Tags: angular, error-handling

When user navigates to a URL, which is not matched to any route, Angular router throws an error

> Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: [...]

What is the correct way of handling this specific error?

When using custom [ErrorHandler](https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler) as specified in the [ExtraOptions](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#errorHandler), this error comes as a generic Error instance, so only way to match is regexp the `err.message`, but that doesn't sound right.

Comment: Hi, why not adding a wild card route and then redirect with a 404 component ?

Comment: You can add a component that serves like 404 page and show some meaningful message and offer routes where to go... Or reroute directly.

Comment: I will probably do it this way, I had an idea a popup would be shown, that the route doesn't lead anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redirect to another route when user navigates to a url which is not matched to any route. All the undefined routes will be redirect to dashboard as per example.

Defined in routes like this ::

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './Component/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'},
   { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
```

Comment: Yes, I could redirect to a 404 page, but isn't there a way to just handle the error and display a popup or something?

Answer (score 0):

you can add  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'default route' }

Answer (score 0):

Hello there is an other way to handle the error throwed by the router:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.errorHandler = (error: any) => {
        // do some stuff
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, but if I am not mistaken, the problem is the same as with gobal errorhandler - I dont have a means of distinguishing the error type.

Comment: On a second thought this kind of error might be the only one Router throws.